# Is there a way to find internal links to a specific web page?

Tags: 7, nodes

For example, for a page called `mysite.com/about` can you determine any other pages that link directly to this web page? The goal is to determine all of the webpages that exist in `mysite.com` that have a link to the `about` page.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Everything is possible. Depends how much time you have. Are the links in link fields? Are the links in body fields? What have you tried so far? You could also just dump the database and open it in a text editor and look for the links. Why do you want it? What do you want to do with the information? You need node IDs of the affected pages? Are you looking for external links or internal links? Please edit your question and make this a reproducible issue, relevant to others. Many thanks

Comment: Seems more of a task for some external link checker SEO tool. 

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module (pretty sure you already have that module enabled ...), which includes a **Backlinks** view. After you activate this view, a <kbd>What links here</kbd>-tab is shown on each node.

So on your *about* page, it'll list all of the pages that have a link to the about page (as in your question).

Answer (score 0):

The comment on the OP seems really dismissive.

Currently there is no way in Drupal to do this. In Drupal 7 there **was** a way to do this. To understand why this is no no longer possible you can digest this here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1853536

(TLDR;)
The capability relied on Core Search Code that was removed and upgraded (original was in-efficient and cause overhead problems).

We do need this capability within Drupal, as Admins, however.

Example:
I have >5k web pages in a Drupal site I've inherited. I need to delete or un-publish a node. **I need to convert all internal** (I said **internal** *not from external*... and so did the OP above...) all internal links that to point to this node, so I must first discern which internal nodes link to this node, else every one of them will break (error 403 page not found).

Example:
An employee at the company has a Bio (node) on the website. Many nodes link to this Bio node (possible that many do). I've been asked to remove this Bio node from the website. The correct thing to do is re-write the text and link on all nodes linking to this node I am about to remove/unpublish.

Why is this core need so difficult to understand?

What I have done to get around this mis-understanding...
I use google. (example. If I am asked to alter every page, for example, leymannx from the website)
Google Search: site:drupal.stackexchange.com/questions "leymannx"
then methodically open each one and edit.

What we need is a way to do this from within our Drupal Admin, however.
Closest I've got is:
/admin/content/files where file usage count is provided.
I looked at my content type for nodes that are web pages on my site (on my site we call this content-type "basic-pages") /admin/content/basic-pages

Looking at the Drupal "View" the presents each one in admin, it seems that "Files" have access to a field type of "Aggregation", which Content Type of "nodes" do not have....

Aggregation fields have an attribute of "Aggregation Settings" which provide the functionality of "SUM(File Usage: Use Count) (Used in)" that I cannot yet work out how to provide to the Content type "nodes".

Close as I've been able to work out so far.
I'll contribute more if I make progress, but it is overwhelming that this is not a common need at this point.

Hope this helps advance progress towards a solution to your question.